# How to trigger by taking div parent class instead of input

Tags: jquery

This is my form and my script where data is triggered from input name.
I want to trigger this function where div class has kg instead of input name

How should I do that?

```js
$(document).on('change paste keyup', "input[name='kg[]']", function() {
  updatedynamicprice($(this));
});

function updatedynamicprice(selector) {
  let kg = $("input[name='kg[]']").val();
  let total_price = 100 * kg;
  $("input[name='price[]']").val(total_price);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="kg">
  <input type="number" name="kg[]" id="input-kg" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-controller">
  <input type="number" name="price[]" id="input-kg" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant script and HTML. For example `updatedynamicprice` is missing

Comment: A `div` does not have 'change', 'paste' or 'keyup' events. Unless you use `contentEditable`. eg: https://jsfiddle.net/n4cL1ybk/

Comment: @Turnip okay then can we use  events to the input type name for those only which parent class has div class ="kg"

Comment: `$(document).on('change paste keyup', ".kg input", function() {
  updatedynamicprice($(this));
});`

Comment: By why not do this on the form level?

Comment: @mplungjan
Actually i have this input name="kg[]" in 5 different form.

Comment: So you need to use closest to navigate to the relevant field

Comment: maybe yes.Can you give example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate using closest and a container

Give classes you can reuse

```js
$(document).on('change paste keyup', function(e) {
  const $parent = $(e.target).closest(".container");
  let qty = $(".qty",$parent).val();
  let total_price = 100 * qty;
  $(".price",$parent).val(total_price);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="kg">
    <input type="number" name="kg[]" class="qty" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-controller">
    <input type="number" name="price[]" class="price" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="pounds">
    <input type="number" name="pounds[]" class="qty" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-controller">
    <input type="number" name="price[]" class="price" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```